# Como usar um Array bidimensional com Javascript (jquery)?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, json

acredito que minha pergunta ficou superficial demais, mas, explico a situação mais detalhadamente:

eu já tenho o código e ele funciona parcialmente segue;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = "dominio.com/json.php";
    $.getJSON(url, function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        $.each(result, function(i, field) {

            var id_rotina = field.id_rotina;
            var treino = field.treino;
            var grupo_id = field.grupo_id;
            var user_id = field.user_id;

            var id_grupo = field.id_grupo;
            var nome_grupo = field.nome_grupo;
            var anatomia = field.anatomia;

            var id_exercicio = field.id_exercicio;
            var nome_exercicio = field.nome_exercicio;
            var repeticoes = field.repeticoes;
            var intervalo = field.intervalo;

            if(treino == 'treino-b'){
                $("#grupo-b").append(
                "<div class='serie'> <div class='mostra-grupo-b'>"
                + nome_grupo
                + "<div class='visualizar'>VER</div>" 
                + "</div>"
                + "<div class='anatomia'>" + anatomia + "</div>"
                + "<table class='grupo-b' align='center'><thead><td class='exe'>Exercício</td><td>Reps</td><td>Int</td></thead><tbody>"
                + "<td>"+ nome_exercicio +"</td>"
                + "<td>"+ repeticoes +"</td>"
                + "<td>"+ intervalo +"</td>"
                + "</tbody></table></div>");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

ele imprime corretamente quando só tem um elemento para ser impresso quando tem mais de um ele duplica a variavel 'nome_grupo' e o table.

minha pergunta realmente é: Como faço para mostrar na tela as variáveis corretamente ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se percebi bem queres combinar os resultados, agrupando-os por `nome_grupo`.

### Exemplo com o teu JSON:

```js
var result = [{
  "id_rotina": "7",
  "treino": "treino-b",
  "grupo_id": "2",
  "user_id": "1",
  "id_grupo": "2",
  "nome_grupo": "Ombro",
  "anatomia": "\"Ombros\"",
  "id_serie": "1",
  "rotina_id": "7",
  "exercicio_id": "5",
  "repeticoes": "3 X 10",
  "intervalo": "1 Min",
  "id_exercicio": "5",
  "nome_exercicio": "Elevacao Lateral Com Halteres"
}, {
  "id_rotina": "7",
  "treino": "treino-b",
  "grupo_id": "2",
  "user_id": "1",
  "id_grupo": "2",
  "nome_grupo": "Ombro",
  "anatomia": "\"Ombros\"",
  "id_serie": "2",
  "rotina_id": "7",
  "exercicio_id": "4",
  "repeticoes": "4 X 8",
  "intervalo": "45 Seg",
  "id_exercicio": "4",
  "nome_exercicio": "Desenvolvimento Por Frente Com Barra"
}, {
  "id_rotina": "8",
  "treino": "treino-b",
  "grupo_id": "1",
  "user_id": "1",
  "id_grupo": "1",
  "nome_grupo": "Trapezio",
  "anatomia": "trapezio",
  "id_serie": "3",
  "rotina_id": "8",
  "exercicio_id": "7",
  "repeticoes": "3 X 12",
  "intervalo": "45 seg",
  "id_exercicio": "7",
  "nome_exercicio": "Remada Alta Com Barra"
}];


$(document).ready(function() {
  var url = "dominio.com/json.php";
  //  $.getJSON(url, function(result) {
  //    console.log(result);
  var $grupo = $("#grupo-b");
  var grupos = {};


  $.each(result, function(i, field) {
    var id_rotina = field.id_rotina;
    var treino = field.treino;
    var grupo_id = field.grupo_id;
    var user_id = field.user_id;

    var id_grupo = field.id_grupo;
    var nome_grupo = field.nome_grupo;
    var anatomia = field.anatomia;

    var id_exercicio = field.id_exercicio;
    var nome_exercicio = field.nome_exercicio;
    var repeticoes = field.repeticoes;
    var intervalo = field.intervalo;
    var tabela = "<table class='grupo-b' align='center'><thead><td class='exe'>Exercício</td><td>Reps</td><td>Int</td></thead><tbody>" +
      "<td>" + nome_exercicio + "</td>" +
      "<td>" + repeticoes + "</td>" +
      "<td>" + intervalo + "</td>" +
      "</tbody></table>";
    if (!grupos[nome_grupo]) {
      grupos[nome_grupo] = ["<div class='serie'> <div class='mostra-grupo-b'>" +
        nome_grupo +
        "<div class='visualizar'>VER</div>" +
        "</div>" +
        "<div class='anatomia'>" + anatomia + "</div>", tabela, "</div>"
      ];
    } else {
      grupos[nome_grupo].splice(-1, 0, tabela);
    }
  });
  var html = Object.keys(grupos).reduce(function(str, nome) {
    return str += grupos[nome].join('');
  }, '');
  $grupo.html(html);
  //  });
});
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin:10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="grupo-b"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você está criando novamente a div com a class serie e não está verificando se ela já existe.

```
var divNomeGrupo =$('div:contains(nome_grupo)');

if (divNomeGrupo){
    divNomeGrupo.parent().append( conteúdo );
} else { 
#executa o código normalmente
  }
```

Comment: nesse caso o nome do grupo não se repete o que se repete é thead onde tem (Reps) e (Int) .. gostaria de saber se esse código do jeito que está é possível mostrar dinamicamente o nome_grupo e atribuir a este nome grupo de forma dinamica o (nome_exercicio) etc sem repetir o thead apenas quando necessário em caso de mostrar um (nome_grupo) diferente .. (com as devidas alterações é claro). Obrigado por responder..

Answer (score 0):

mais uma vez o amigo Sergio salvando o dia .. esse é o código que me atendeu, com as devidas modificações (resolvi alterar caso mais alguem precise da mesma solução) :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = "http://dominio.com/json.php";
    $.getJSON(url, function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        var $grupo = $("#grupo-b");
        var grupos = {};
            $.each(result, function(i, field) {
                var treino = field.treino;
                var nome_grupo = field.nome_grupo;
                var anatomia = field.anatomia;
                var nome_exercicio = field.nome_exercicio;
                var repeticoes = field.repeticoes;
                var intervalo = field.intervalo;

                var tabela = "<table class='grupo-b' align='center'><tbody>" +
                "<td class='exe'>" + nome_exercicio + "</td>" +
                "<td class='reps'>" + repeticoes + "</td>" +
                "<td class='int'>" + intervalo + "</td>" +
                "</tbody></table>";
                if (!grupos[nome_grupo]) {
                  grupos[nome_grupo] = ["<div class='serie'> <div class='mostra-grupo-b'>" +
                    nome_grupo +
                    "<div class='visualizar'>VER</div>" +
                    "</div>" +
                    "<table class='grupo-b' align='center'><thead><td class='exe'>Exercício</td><td class='reps'>Reps</td><td class='int'>Int</td></thead></table>"+
                    "<div class='anatomia'>" + anatomia + "</div>", tabela, "</div>"
                  ];
                }else{
                    grupos[nome_grupo].splice(-1, 0, tabela);
                }
            });
        var html = Object.keys(grupos).reduce(function(str, nome) {
            return str += grupos[nome].join('');
        }, '');
    $grupo.html(html);
    });
});
```